# in order traversal of binary tree into list

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to create recursive function for inorder traversal for following tree Interface

```
// EFFECTS: returns true if tree is empty, false otherwise
bool tree_isEmpty (const tree_t& tree);
// EFFECTS: creates an empty tree.
tree_t tree_make ();
// EFFECTS: creates a new tree, with elt as it's element, left as
// its left subtree, and right as its right subtree
tree_t tree_make (int elt, const tree_t& left, const tree_t& right);
// REQUIRES: tree is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the element at the top of tree.
int tree_elt (const tree_t& tree);
// REQUIRES: tree is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the left subtree of tree
tree_t tree_left (const tree_t& tree);
// REQUIRES: tree is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the right subtree of tree
tree_t tree_right (const tree_t& tree);
// MODIFIES: cout
// EFFECTS: prints tree to cout.
void tree_print (const tree_t& tree);
```

i can not use for,while or goto loops i tried creating function but unfortunately it dosen't work please help.my function is below

```
list_t traversal_helper(tree_t tree,list_t l){

    if (tree.is_empty())
        return l;

    /* first recur on left child */
    traversal_helper (tree.get_left_tree(),l);

    /* then print the data of node */
    l=list_make(tree.get_elt(),l);

    /* now recur on right child */
    traversal_helper (tree.get_right_tree(),l);
    }


list_t traversal(tree_t tree){
    list_t l=list_make();
    if(tree.is_empty()){
        return list_make();
    }
    else{
        return traversal_helper(tree,l);
    }
}

My list_t interface contain following functions:

List Interface
The file recursive.h defines the type "list_t" and the following operations on lists:
// EFFECTS: returns true if list is empty, false otherwise
bool list_isEmpty​ (const list_t& list);
// EFFECTS: returns an empty list.
list_t list_make​ ();
// EFFECTS: given the list (list) make a new list consisting of
// the new element followed by the elements of the
// original list.
list_t list_make​ (int elt, const list_t& list);
// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the first element of list
int list_first​ (const list_t& list);
// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the list containing all but the first element of list
list_t list_rest​ (const list_t& list);
// MODIFIES: cout
// EFFECTS: prints list to cout.
void list_print​ (const list_t& list);
```

Comment: *but unfortunately it dosen't work* Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You may be passing `list_t` object by value (depending on its definition).

Comment: i edited my post can i pass this by pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`traversal_helper` never returns anything, and it does not use the return value of the recursive calls - I guess you want something like this:

```
list_t traversal_helper(tree_t tree,list_t l){

    if (tree.is_empty())
        return l;

    /* first recur on left child */
    l = traversal_helper (tree.get_left_tree(),l);

    /* then print the data of node */
    l=list_make(tree.get_elt(),l);

    /* now recur on right child */
    return traversal_helper (tree.get_right_tree(),l);
}
```

this should work if `list_make` creates a new list appending the element at the end of the list. If it appends the element at the start of the list then the result will need to be reversed.